# SEO of <span> in <h1> header

Tags: seo, html

Does the `<span>` element have any SEO side-effects? Are there any semantic preferences between the following two or parsing differences between search engines?

### Clean `<h1>`:

```
<h1>Search Optimised Heading</h1>
```

### vs `<span>` in `<h1>`:

```
<h1>Search <span class="someColour">Optimised</span> Heading</h1>
```

Comment: I think there is no difference between your two examples,too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be no difference. The `<span>` element has no semantic meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 14):

There is no difference between your two examples. However, if your differently-coloured word is an important keyword, you may consider using the `<em>` or `<strong>` tag to suggest emphasis. CSS can take care of the styling:

```
h1 em {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #123456;
}
```

Emphasis usually boosts SEO a little, although I don't know how much difference it makes when inside a header. Regardless, it makes for some simpler and more semantic HTML which is always a bonus.